# How do I pass the Hadoop Streaming -file flag to Amazon ElasticMapreduce?

Tags: elastic-map-reduce, hadoop-streaming

The `-file` flag allows you to pack your executable files as a part of job submission and thus allow you to run a MapReduce without first manually copying the executable to S3. Is there a way to use the `-file` flag with Amazon's elastic-mapreduce command? If not, what is the easiest way to upload the binary you want to run?

Comment: Are you asking that what is the easiest way to upload your binary to S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. I ended up uploading the executable separately from invoking elastic-mapreduce.